# Visual Studio - is there a way to insert a blank line at the end of files in Visual Studio 2019 (the IDE, NOT vscode)?

Tags: visual-studio

I really dislike that VS2019 doesn't insert a blank line at the end of files and ensures there's always a blank line when you save a file. I feel like there *has* to be an option for that but the only thing I could find on Google were questions on how to *remove* blank lines at the end of files, mostly related to vscode.

Comment: Are you using an `.editorconfig` file with this specified inside? Also, if these are source code, what language are you using?

Comment: @DrewNoakes I'm currently not using a .editorconfig. I'd like this to be a local global setting so preferably not per filetype. My source files are mostly C#, xaml and xml.

Comment: I asked about language because VS uses different editors for different file types, and they may not all respect `.editorconfig`. It's possible to configure an `.editorconfig` file to apply to all file types. Use `insert_final_newline=true` to control this. I would expect this to work. If it does not, I will file a bug internally.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, it now works with the `.editorconfig` file! It still seems a little strange to me that it can only be done this way and not through VS's options dialog but this works for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Drew Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24874/drew-noakes) suggested, add a `.editorconfig` file with the line

```
insert_final_newline = true
```